# Encrypt data using c# and decrypt it using openssl api, why there are lots of trashy padding at the end of decrypted data?

Tags: c#, c, encryption, openssl, rsa

I using RSA(1024) to encrypt/decrypt strings. The encryption is implemented using public key and is written in C#, and the decryption is implementation by c. I encrypt the string:

> 86afaecb-c211-4d55-8e90-2b715d6d64b9

and write the encrypted data to a file. Then, I using openssl api to read the encrypted data from the file and decrypt it. However, I got the output as:

> 86afaecb-c211-4d55-8e90-2b715d6d64b9oeheBjQ8fo1AmDnor1D3BLuPyq9wJBAOV+M/WVNYzYr
>   PJBKoskOj+4LaNpT+SpkfK81nsnQEbHbjgao4eHNU+PmWl9

It seems that there are some trashy padding at the end of original string. Why It Occurs? And how to solve the problem?

Some code snippet is shown below:

```
// Encrypt
{
    string plainData = “86afaecb-c211-4d55-8e90-2b715d6d64b9”;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.ImportParameters(paraPub);
    byte[] testData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainData);
    byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(testData, true);
    FileStream pFileStream = null;
    string fileName = "encryptedData.dat";
    pFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    pFileStream.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
    ...
}

// Decrypt
{
    char *encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(privateKey));
    FILE *out = fopen("encryptedData.dat", "r");
    int encrypt_len = fread(encrypt, sizeof(*encrypt), RSA_size(privateKey), out);
    fclose(out);

    decrypt = malloc(encrypt_len);
    if(RSA_private_decrypt(encrypt_len, 
                          (unsigned char*)encrypt, 
                          (unsigned char*)decrypt, 
                          privateKey, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) == -1) {
        // error handle
    }

    printf("Decrypted message: %s\n", decrypt);
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `decrypt` is null-terminated in `RSA_private_decrypt()`? And that `encrypt_len` has proper value? And most important - is that rubbish after your decrypted value always the same, or is it random after each decryption?

Comment: Your encryption method does not appear to specify a padding.  Your decryption method specifies OAEP padding.  You may have a padding mismatch here.

Comment: Have you tried to use rsa.Encrypt(testData, false); and RSA_PKCS1_PADDING instead RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING? Just to verify that the problems isn't PKCS#1 v2.

Comment: Note that OAEP is better than PKCS#1 v1.5 in almost all cases.

Comment: @KamilT, I have the declaration "char *decrypt = NULL" before above codes, and encrypt_len is 128 that is the same as the length of public key. As you point out, the rubbish is always the same.

Comment: Just a question from this C noob: does `sizeof` work on a dynamically allocated array? How does it determine the size? Furthermore, I think you are expecting a zero terminated string in C. C# does not work with zero terminated strings AFAIK (and this is probably the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem by initializing the decrypt using "`memset(decrypt, 0, encrypt_len);`" after "`decrypt = malloc(encrypt_len);`". Thx everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you should use the decrypted size instead of directly treating the output of the decryption as a null terminated string.

> `RSA_private_decrypt()` returns the size of the recovered plaintext.